# How much space is recommended for a Windows 7 Bootcamp installation besides Snow Leopard?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, disk-space

How much space is recommended for a Windows 7 Bootcamp installation besides Snow Leopard? I thought of 30 Gigabyte. Would that be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Parallels virtual HDD has 12GB. But I using windows only in sometimes.

The space is depend on what you want install into windows. And really need BootCamp? Parallels or VMware or VirtualBox(free) is fine - why you need BootCamp?

Comment: Recently I found a game in my shelf and the desire to play it grew in my stomach. Sadly it is a Windows-Only-Game. And because I have only a MacBook I thought of installing Windows 7 to satisfy my desire. :-)

Comment: you can test the Parallels - demo download. Parallels emulating DirectX nicely, so it is possible play games too. You can try it for performance - and you will be surprised. ;) Anyway, Parallels can use the BootCamp windows - so you can give a try: 12GB for minimum (Windows7 + office + basic work place) and add space needed for other sw.

Comment: Parallels sounds interesting. But since it is not free, I think I'll go for BootCamp first. Thank you!